# Getting the distance in km between two coordinates within Hungary

Tags: postgis, distance

I have a table called properties (generated with `EF Core`) which has a column called `GeoPoint`. In the database, this column is a `geomerty(Point)` type. All properties are located within Hungary. I am trying to create a procedure for search properties within a distance of a specific coordinate.

Distance should be in meters.

Properties table has two `text` columns, longitude, latitude, which I have used to populate this new extra column called `GeoPoint` and I have used the following script to do this.

```
UPDATE "Properties" SET "GeoPoint" = (ST_MakePoint(CAST("Longitude" AS double precision), CAST("Latitude" AS double precision)))
```

After this I had all my `GeoPoint` columns populated, but not sure if this was the correct way.

To search I tried to use the following script

```
SELECT p."Id", p."Longitude", p."Latitude", p."GeoPoint" 
FROM "Properties" p
WHERE ST_DWithin(
        p."GeoPoint",
        ST_Transform(
            ST_GeomFromText(
                'POINT(19.081750000000 47.54770000000)',
                4326),
            2100),
        5000)
```

and I get the following error;

> ERROR:  LWGEOM_dwithin: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (Point, 0) != (Point, 2100)

I am completely new to PostGIS, but it seems like the script I have used to populate the `GeoPoint` columns is incorrect.

UPDATE:

I have changed my update script to

```
UPDATE "Properties" SET "GeoPoint" = ST_SetSRID((ST_MakePoint(CAST("Longitude" AS double precision), CAST("Latitude" AS double precision))), 23700)
```

and my select statement to

```
SELECT p."Id", p."Longitude", p."Latitude", p."GeoPoint" 
FROM "Properties" p
WHERE ST_DWithin(
        p."GeoPoint",
        ST_Transform(
            ST_GeomFromText(
                'POINT(19.081750000000 47.54770000000)',
                4326),
            23700),
        500000)
```

Running this select statement returns no error, but it does not return any results either. Distance is set to 500000, which should be 500 km
and the table contains multiple sample record within 3 to 20 km distance.
If I change the distance to 5 000 000, then it returns all rows even some located 17+ km away

UPDATE AGAIN:

I have googled it and SRID 23700 supposed to be the correct one Hungary and distance should be in meters. I still do not get it. If I run the following:

```
select ST_Distance(
'SRID=23700;POINT(19.067931856332 47.511673637045)'::geometry, 
'SRID=23700;POINT(19.081750000000 47.54770000000)'::geometry)
```

It returns `0.03858548849237025` which is clearly not in meters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There seems to be a projection issue. You convert yor WGS84 coordinates to EPSG:2100 which is valid for Greece: https://epsg.io/2100 - look for a projected CRS valid for Hungary and than first re-project your points to this.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have found it: https://epsg.io/23700 - but I still get the same error. Does these mean I have to set this `id` when I populate the `GeoPoint` columns as well? It still says `operation on mixed SRID geometries`

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain the error message. Note that best practice is to use all lowercase column names, so you don't need to double-quote every column identifier.

Comment: @Vince thanks for the advice ont hte column names. The error message is already in the  first part of the question. The edited select statement does not return any error message, but the results are incorrect

Comment: when you set `geopoint`, you are using lat-longs and you assign srid 23700. I seems you should assign 4326 and then do a transform to 23700. The strange results you get occurs because your points are around coordinates 0m;0m(+- 90 meters / +-180 meters) instead of degrees

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not get it. I think Hungarian SRID is 23700 and I do not understand why should I convert it to 4326 first. Also how do I get the distance in meters or kms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ST_Distance` and `ST_DWithin` uses the projection metrics. If your projection is in meter it will uses meters, but if your projection is in degree it will uses degrees.

In your case, you want meters, and your projection is in meter, so it should be good. I think the problem is that your data is in degree. When you use the function `ST_SetSRID` it does not project your data, it just set the projection so all the function you use will recognize this field as a geometry in this projection. If you have longitude and latitude, your projection is 4326. If you want your data in 23700, you need to transform it.

So for example when you do:

```
select ST_Distance(
'SRID=23700;POINT(19.067931856332 47.511673637045)'::geometry, 
'SRID=23700;POINT(19.081750000000 47.54770000000)'::geometry)
```

You define 2 points around 19 meter in X and 47 meter in Y in the 23700. But that's clearly GPS point, so in 4326. I you want them in 23700, you need to do:

```
select ST_Distance(
ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(19.067931856332 47.511673637045)'::geometry, 23700), 
ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(19.081750000000 47.54770000000)'::geometry, 23700))
```

So you need to modify your update script to add the transform:

```
ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID((ST_MakePoint(CAST("Longitude" AS double precision), CAST("Latitude" AS double precision))), 4326), 23700)
```

You could also not use any projection and work directly in 4326, and use `ST_Distance` or `ST_DWithin` with your geom::geography to use them with meters. Postgis will automatically project using UTM if possible.